# Simultaneous HTTP requests in PHP with cURL

Tags: php, loops, curl

I'm trying to take a rather large list of domains query the rank of each using the compete.com API as seen here -> https://www.compete.com/developer/documentation

The script I wrote takes a database of domains I populated and initiates a cURL request to compete for the rank of the website. I quickly realized that this was very slow because each request was being sent one at a time. I did some searching and came across this post-> http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/ which explains how to perform simultaneous HTTP requests in PHP with cURL.

Unfortunately that script will take an array of 25,000 domains and try to process them all at once. I found that batches of 1,000 work quite well.

***Any idea how to send 1,000 queries to compete.com then wait for completion and send the next 1,000 until the array is empty?*** Here's what I'm workin with thus far:

```
<?php

//includes
include('includes/mysql.php');
include('includes/config.php');

//get domains
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $competeRequests[] = "http://apps.compete.com/sites/" . $row['Domain'] . "/trended/rank/?apikey=xxx&start_date=201207&end_date=201208&jsonp=";
}

//first batch
$curlRequest = multiRequest($competeRequests);
$j = 0;
foreach ($curlRequest as $json){
    $j++;
    $json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $rank = $json_output[data][trends][rank][0][value];

    if($rank) {
        //Create mysql query
        $query = "Update $tableName SET Rank = '$rank' WHERE ID  = '$j'";

        //Execute the query
        mysql_query($query);
        echo $query . "<br/>";
    }
}


function multiRequest($data) {
  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;

}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't see a question in there.

Comment: Looking for a way to run 1000 domain batch rank check for 25k domains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
//first batch
$curlRequest = multiRequest($competeRequests);

$j = 0;
foreach ($curlRequest as $json){
```

You can do:

```
$curlRequest = array();

foreach (array_chunk($competeRequests, 1000) as $requests) {
    $results = multiRequest($requests);

    $curlRequest = array_merge($curlRequest, $results);
}

$j = 0;
foreach ($curlRequest as $json){
    $j++;
    // ...
```

This will split the large array into chunks of 1,000 and pass those 1,000 values to your `multiRequest` function which uses cURL to execute those requets.

Comment: Is there a way to execute 1,000 then echo results then continue? As of now the script takes several minutes to run and it just shows a loading screen the entire time. Any ideas for progress bar / status updates?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/ShadowHostCloak

This does exactly what you want. Just pass empty argument to `new Proxy()` to bypass proxy and make direct requests.

You can stuff 1000 requests in it and call `$proxy->execWait()` and it will process all requests simultaneously and exit that method when everything is done... Then you can repeat.